# Jenkins - mvn not found

Tags: java, azure, maven, jenkins

Hello I'm new to jenkins and getting this issue. I'm using jenkins in windows azure

> - mvn clean package /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/vcc@tmp/durable-b5407f14/script.sh: 2:
>     /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/vcc@tmp/durable-b5407f14/script.sh: mvn:
>     not found.

Jenkinsfiles:

```
node {
   stage('init') {
      checkout scm
   }
   stage('build') {
      sh '''
         mvn clean package
         cd target
         cp ../src/main/resources/web.config web.config
         cp todo-app-java-on-azure-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar 
         zip todo.zip app.jar web.config
      '''
   }
   stage('deploy') {
      azureWebAppPublish azureCredentialsId: env.AZURE_CRED_ID,
      resourceGroup: env.RES_GROUP, appName: env.WEB_APP, filePath: "**/todo.zip"
   }
}
```

can any body help me how can I resolve this mvn issue.

P.S I'm following this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/tutorial-jenkins-deploy-web-app-azure-app-service

Comment: Is apache-maven installed on the machine? Try mvn --version from the command line.

Comment: @DezsoGabos thanks I think that was an issue , but after installing maven error has changed now but still get it

`The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/vcc). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.`

Comment: @ArsalanK well... is there a pom in that directory?

Comment: Make sure after you checkout from the SCM you change to the directory in the workspace where your pom.xml is.

Comment: @ArsalanK Your original question seems to be solved. If you have a different problem, please open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to add maven tool to your pipeline:

```
 tools {
    maven 'M3'
  }
  stages {
   stage('init') {
      checkout scm
   }
   stage('build') {
      sh '''
         mvn clean package
         cd target
         cp ../src/main/resources/web.config web.config
         cp todo-app-java-on-azure-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar 
         zip todo.zip app.jar web.config
      '''
   }
   stage('deploy') {
      azureWebAppPublish azureCredentialsId: env.AZURE_CRED_ID,
      resourceGroup: env.RES_GROUP, appName: env.WEB_APP, filePath: "**/todo.zip"
   }
}
```

Comment: The "M3" name on the answer should be the name of one of the maven installations. (Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Global Tools Configuration)

Answer (score 2):

You may wanna check if Jenkins has the pipeline-maven plugin installed.
If you don't have it, search and install the pipeline-maven plugin.

[image: Pipeline-maven plugin]

Once the plugin is installed, you can use maven as follows

```
node{
    stage('init'){
      //init sample
    }
    stage('build'){
        withMaven(maven: 'mvn') {
            sh "mvn clean package"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I add this line right before sh command in the build stage : `def mvnHome = tool name: 'Apache Maven 3.6.0', type: 'maven'` 
 and instead of mvn you should use `${mvnHome}/bin/mvn`

thank [this youtube film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pts8zdHel5E) to help me.

```
 pipeline{
  stage('com'){
    def mvnHome = tool name: 'Apache Maven 3.6.0', type: 'maven'
    sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B -DskipTests clean package"
  }
}
```